# Angular service injection failing to load into controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently a simple app that contains a controller and a service. It looks like the service loads correctly into the module but the controller isn't picking it up. If I remove the 'Photo' injection from the controller, the code doesn't crash. It's only when I try to inject the service into the controller that I see a problem.

controllers.js file:

```
var photoViewer= angular.module('photoViewer', ['photoViewer.services']);

photoViewer.controller('PhotoListCtrl', ['$scope', 'Photo', function($scope, Photo) {
    $scope.photos = Photo.getPhotos();
}]);
```

services.js file:

```
angular.module('photoViewer.services', [], function($provide) {
    $provide.factory('Photo', ['$resource', function($resource){
        return {
            getPhotos: function() {
                return [
                    {'name': 'test1'},
                    {'name': 'test2'}
                ];
            }
        }
    }]);
});
```

Html file:

```
<html ng-app="photoViewer">
<head>
    <title>Photo Viewer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="PhotoListCtrl" style="width:500px;">
        <div>{{photos.length}} total photos found.</div>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="photo in photos">
                {{$index + 1}} - {{photo.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="/js/libs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/controllers.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$provide.factory('Photo', ['$resource', function($resource){` has a dependency on `$resource` which it seems you haven't included.

Here are the docs on `$resource`:

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource

Comment: Thank you! That was indeed the problem.